# Newcommand with macros as input

Tags: macros

I have defined two arrays of points like so:

```
\def\blah{{0,1,2,3},{0,1,2,3}}
\def\foo{{0,1,2,3},{3,2,1,0}}
```

I want to use these points in a `TikZ` image. Since I have a lot of these arrays, I wanted to create a newcommand, say:

```
\newcommand{\imagemap}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \row [count=\j] in #1 {
    \foreach \elem [count=\i] in \row {
      \draw (\i,\j)--(\j,\i);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

So I can use `\imagemap{foo}` or `\imagemap{blah}` without having to redefine a new command for each array. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

What does work is `\imagemap{\foo}` and `\imagemap{\blah}`. Is there any way to rejigger the command so that I don't have to use the slash inside the braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course:

```
\newcommand{\imagemap}[1]{%
  \expandafter\doimagemap\csname #1\endcsname
}

\newcommand{\doimagemap}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \row [count=\j] in #1 {
      \foreach \elem [count=\i] in \row {
        \draw (\i,\j)--(\j,\i);
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

The trick is to define `\imagemap` to build the single token (with the backslash added, so to speak) before `\doimagemap` enters into action. The construction for building control sequences from strings is `\csname`; the end of the string is signalled by `\endcsname`.

Comment: That was embarrasingly simple! I will accept this as soon as the timer is up.